# Landscape view controller presented from portrait view controller occasionally appears in portrait orientation with landscape bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, landscape

I have a simple app in which a portrait `UINavigationController` presents a landscape `UINavigationController`. Usually it works fine. Sometimes though, the landscape view controller appears in portrait orientation, but with landscape bounds.

Here's how it works: to restrict the orientation of the navigation controllers, I have a class, `OrientableNavigationController` that derives from `UINavigationController` and exposes the rotation-specific properties:

```
class OrientableNavigationController: UINavigationController {
  private var _supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .all
  private var _shouldAutorotate: Bool = false
  private var _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation = .portrait

  override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    get { return _supportedInterfaceOrientations }
    set { _supportedInterfaceOrientations = newValue }
  }

  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    get { return _shouldAutorotate }
    set { _shouldAutorotate = newValue }
  }

  override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    get { return _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation }
    set { _preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation = newValue }
  }
}
```

I init one of these within the AppDelegate, give it a view controller and set it as the `rootViewController` of the window:

```
private var portraitNavigationController = OrientableNavigationController()

func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  portraitNavigationController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = .portrait
  portraitNavigationController.shouldAutorotate = true
  portraitNavigationController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation = .portrait

  let portraitViewController = PortraitViewController()
  portraitViewController.delegate = self

  portraitNavigationController.pushViewController(portraitViewController, animated: false)

  window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  window!.rootViewController = portraitNavigationController

  window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

And that 'Present Landscape View Controller' button is hooked up to do this:

```
func portraitViewControllerButtonWasTouched(_ viewController: PortraitViewController) {
    let landscapeNavigationController = OrientableNavigationController()
    landscapeNavigationController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = .landscape
    landscapeNavigationController.shouldAutorotate = true
    landscapeNavigationController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation = .landscapeLeft
    landscapeNavigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    let landscapeViewController = LandscapeViewController()

    landscapeNavigationController.pushViewController(landscapeViewController, animated: false)

    portraitNavigationController.present(landscapeNavigationController, animated: true)
  }
```

Most of the time, this works fine. The landscape view controller is presented like so:

[image]

But *sometimes*, this happens:

[image]

This occurs in both simulator and device. Any ideas?

Comment: Does rotating the device after the misaligned vc comes up change anything?

Comment: No, rotation has no affect. But if press the home button, the view appears correctly once I reopen the app.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when setting `landscapeViewController ` as the rootViewController when initialising your `UINavigationController` subclass?

Failing that perhaps try delaying the presentation of the navigation controller to the start of the next runloop? Another alternative would be to listen to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`s `navigationController:didShow:animated:` and presenting the navigation controller there.

Comment: Setting as rootViewController: no dice. Delaying presentation (with dispatch.async.main), also no dice. The only way I could avoid this bug was to present as portrait and transform the view with a CGAffineTransform.